# Tableau first sum by hour and then average by day

Tags: sum, average, tableau-api, days, hour

I have data in this form. For each day and hour I have demand data. I want to first find the total demand by each hour. And then plot the daily average for the month. How would I do that?

```
Date|Hour|Zone|Demand
1/1/2016|1|100|1000
1/1/2016|2|100|900
1/1/2016|3|100|950
...
1/1/2016|1|200|50
1/1/2016|2|200|46
1/1/2016|3|200|52
...
```

And so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. Hope it helps

- Drag 'MDY[Date]' in columns & 'SUM[Demand]' in rows
- Convert 'Hour' to dimension, if it's not. Drag it to 'Color' Marks. Change it to bar graph.
- Drag 'AVG[Demand]' in rows. In Marks, remove 'Hour' from 'Color' of 'AVG[Demand]' Marks. Change it to line graph.

You can very well play around with graph mode and other cosmetic changes you would like.